# Is the sentence "games that have us like (whoa sign)" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is the following sentence correct:

> Games that have us like (whoa sign)

The sentence above is a heading of the description of the most interesting apps in 2019.

I am curious to know if the sentence "Games that have us like (without whoa sign)" makes any sense. Let me make this clear that in the sentence above I am asking if the sentence makes any sense without whoa sign.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "games that have us like" makes sense, but it's an incomplete thought.

The meaning of the phrase "games that have us like, 'whoa'" (or however you might spell that) is *games that when played, or watched, made us react with astonishment*.

More generally, the phrase "[noun/pronoun] has us like [reaction]" means *the noun/pronoun caused us to feel the stated way*.

For example, a quick search turns up these two results:

"[Her] booty has me like, whoa" - *when I see her butt, I am astonished*

"Instagram stories got me like, you all need to listen to better music" - *when I see your Instagram stories, I feel like you need to listen to better music*.

This construction is slang and should only be used in contexts where slang is appropriate.

So, "games that have us like" makes sense, but demands more information, just the same as the phrase, "books that make us think of" - think of what?

Comment: I think more of stereotypical white Californians than black Americans when I hear a phrase like this. I could very easily imagine the speaker with a surfboard and bleached-blond hair.

Comment: @AeonAkechi, could be.  I'll update my answer to remove this bit of unnecessary speculation.

Comment: What is a 'whoa sign'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, that's a good question.  I answered this question on the assumption that a whoa sign was some kind of pictorial representation of a person saying "whoa" - like an emoji, for instance.

Comment: So the sentence fragment is akin to e.g. 'things that make us - like - 'yuk' (which is a way of saying 'things that are repulsive or unappetising' in an inanely informal way)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, yes, but I don't find the phrase any more inane than older variations on the theme, like "it made me go, yuck."  Was the meaning not clear from my answer, and if so, how could I improve it?

Comment: Your answer is fine. I was ranting about what used to be called 'Valley talk' and is now the way everybody under 30 talks. As I said, repulsively inane.

Comment: @Juhasz, I am assuming that the quoted sentence does not make any sense without the whoa emoji. In other words, the sentence "games that have us like (without the whoa emoji)" doesn't mean anything. Am I correct?

Comment: @curious, that's the same question I answered above. "Games that have us like" is an incomplete sentence, and its meaning is described above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a [complete sentence](https://www.le.ac.uk/oerresources/ssds/grammarguides/page_02.htm) because it demands further information: What do these games do or what did somebody do to them? The verb *has* does not create a complete sentence because it is in a subordinate clause introduced by *that*.

It is a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) or nominal, since it is a combination of words that expresses an idea that might be the subject or object of a complete sentence.